# How to call activity from the items of the spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I have a page which consist of a spinner and a submit button. What I want to achieve is when user selects an item in the list and click on submit, it should take him to an other layout having a webview. Each item in the spinner should open different .html page in the layout.

What I have now is the item is being selected from the spinner, but I'm not sure how to perform onclick listener to it...

code for main activity.java is:

```
    public class beef extends Activity {

private Spinner spinner1;
private ImageButton btnSubmit;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.beef);


    addListenerOnButton();
    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();

}


public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection(){

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
}

//get the selected dropdown list value
public void addListenerOnButton() {

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    btnSubmit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(v.getId() == btnSubmit.getId())
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(beef.this,display.class);
                intent.putExtra("urlpath", "animalbites.html");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

    });

}
```

}

code of CustomOnItemSelectedListener.java is:

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if (arg2 == 0) // First item selected
    {
    //Here I need to give an id for the .html file  

    }
    else if (arg2 == 1) // Second
    {
            //Here I need to give an id for the .html file  
    }



    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

and the display.java is:

```
public class display extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private WebView webView;

     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.webview);

            Intent intent=getIntent();
            String mUrl=intent.getStringExtra("urlpath");
            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/"+mUrl);


     }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, its simple. Here is what I did:

```
public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection(){

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
   - - - 


@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(v.getId() == btnSubmit.getId())
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(beef.this,display.class);
                    intent.putExtra("urlpath", mLink);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }

        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(arg2==0){
            mLink="Beef html/BBQ_Meatballs_Recipes.html";
        }
}

@Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

i am not exactly getting your problem, but i ll answer according to what i got:

Why are you concerned of adding an onClickListener to the spinner?

Just add onClickListener to the button and on the click of that button do:

```
    String selecteditemName=(String)spinner1.getSelectedItem();
    //spinner1 having items : "file1" , "file2"

    Intent i=new Intent(this, yournewActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("selected_item", selecteditemName);
    startActivity(i);
```

Now in that activity (yournewActivity) containing the webview use this code in onCreate() method:

```
    String item;
    Intent i=getIntent();
    item = i.getStringExtra("selected_item");
```

Now you have your spinner selection in the String 'item', you can now do whatever you want:

My point is that : You should use your spinner selection as ID for populating the webview.

If you still want to use any IDs other than the ones present in the spinner then
make an extra java class Idgetter,

```
    class idgetter
{
    public static String getID(String name)
    {
        if(name.equals("file1"))
            return "requiredfile1.html";

        else if(name.equals("file2"))
            return "requiredfile2.html";
    }
}
```

Now, Do exactly as the above code says and after you have the spinner selection in the variable item , use:

```
    String id=idgetter.getID(item);   //in younewActivity
```

You are finally done.

Answer (score 0):

By using Intent's putExtra method.

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, display.class);
mIntent.putExtra("urlpath", "put value in here");
startActivity(mIntent);
```

Comment: Hi IvanFel,
I have already used it, can you please tel me where else to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Populate the spinner with number of html pages and Use spinner.getSelectedItem().toString() inside the addListenerOnButton() method. By doing do, you will get the selected html page and pass it using intent to the next layout.

CODE:

> `public class beef extends Activity {
>
> private Spinner spinner1;
>   private ImageButton btnSubmit;
>
> int final websiteA = 1;
>   int final websiteB = 2;
>   int final websiteC = 3;
>
> String selectedHtmlPage = "";

```
.........
.........
.........


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) 
{
    switch(arg2)
    {
        case websiteA :
            selectedHtmlPage = "websiteA.html";
            break;
        case websiteB :
            selectedHtmlPage = "websiteB.html";
            break;
        case websiteC :
            selectedHtmlPage = "websiteC.html";
            break;
    }
}

public void addListenerOnButton()
{
    btnSubmit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if(v.getId() == btnSubmit.getId())
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(beef.this,display.class);
                intent.putExtra("urlpath", selectedHtmlPage);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

    });

}
```

}`

Comment: spinner argument starts from zero. so initialize final int values from 0